# Retrieve date format and parse if needed in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datetime

I've created this function when retrieving a date from database and echo in Italian format to screen:

```
function get_data_ita($date) {
    if ($date == "")
        return "";

    $d = new DateTime($date);
    return $d->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

where `$date` is mysql format like: `2017-12-31 14:00:00`

Now, if I pass a correct format like: `2017-12-31 14:00:00` the function works.
But sometimes I need to use the SAME function, passing an already formatted date like: `30/12/2017`. In this case, i get parsing error of course.

How can I check if date passed is already in Italian format, and if yes return the untouched date, if not, parse the date?
I need a function like:

```
function get_data_ita($date) {
    if ( $date== ALREADY_IN_ITALIAN_FORMAT )
       return $date;

    if ($date == "")
        return "";

    $d = new DateTime($date);
    return $d->format('d/m/Y');
}

echo get_data_ita("30/12/2017");
echo get_data_ita("2017-12-31 14:00:00");
```

ECHO:

```
30/12/2017
31/12/2017
```

UPDATE: I found solution myself:

```
function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
    $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
    return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}

function get_data_ita($datetime_db) {

    if ( validateDate($datetime_db, 'd/m/Y') ) {
        return $datetime_db;
    }

    if ($datetime_db == "")
        return "";

    $date = new DateTime($datetime_db);
    return $date->format('d/m/Y');

}
```

Comment: You can't google? http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I don't know how to check is a date is already parsed

Comment: why don't u use PHP `date()` function to achieve this?

Comment: Well one difference is the use of `/` in your italian date, when the database gives you a `-` separator.... there's no magic that you can juse, because they're just strings as far as PHP is concerned

Comment: use regex or DateTime::createFromFormat function to test data format

Comment: @PrateikDarji - Because using DateTime objects is a far better approach, because it's timezone and daylight savings aware already, and DateTime objects provide some powerful tools for intervals and periods and working with the difference between two dates, etc.....

Comment: Okay, i got it thank you @MarkBaker

Comment: i've update my post with a good solution...i think

Answer (score 0):

Replace `/` to `-`

```
<?php

function get_data_ita($date) {
    if ($date == ""){
        return "";
    }
    $date = str_replace('/','-',$date);

    $d = new DateTime($date);
    return $d->format('d/m/Y');

}

echo get_data_ita("30/12/2017");
echo "\n";
echo get_data_ita("2017-12-31 14:00:00");

?>
```

Check demo : https://eval.in/918149

Answer (score 0):

Strtotime returns false if the date is not a valid date format.

This works for your inputs but not if there are other date formats.

```
function get_data_ita($date) {
    if ($date == "") return "";

    If(strtotime($date) !== False){
        $d = new DateTime($date);    
    }Else{
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $date);
    }
    return $d->format('d/m/Y');

}

echo get_data_ita("30/12/2017");
echo get_data_ita("2017-12-31 14:00:00");
```

https://3v4l.org/kt5Vg